# How to show default string in v-autocomplete field?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Here's my v-autocomplete component.

```
<v-autocomplete
  v-model="selectedPlace"
  :items="locationList"
  :search-input.sync="query"
  color="#e1b753"
  clearable
  item-text="title"
  item-value="id"
  label="Address"
  return-object
  required
  close-on-content-click
  class="pt-3 pb-0"
  item-width="200"
  :filter="v => v"
  @change="setPlace()"
  @blur="setPlace()"
>
  <template v-slot:item="data">
    <template>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title v-html="data.item.title" />
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
 </template>
</v-autocomplete>
```

When it's empty and the user first sets their address it works just fine but if they reload the page the autocomplete field is empty. I want to set its value according to user's information I get from the server but I can't figure out how.

What I've tried so far:

1. Set locationList[0] to the item I need and used auto-select-fist on autocomplete. It shows the needed location in the dropdown but doesn't display the value in the input.
2. Same as first but also set v-model to "locationList[0]". It displays the value in the input but doesn't let me change or clear it. When I select and remove the text it just jumps back in.

I guess auto-select-first should do the job, but it doesn't, am I trying to use it wrong?

Comment: You would set the default value in the defined `v-model` relationship on `selectedPlace`. So when you get back the data from the server, `this.selectedPlace = locationList[0]`

Comment: what is the value of `selectedPlace` received from the server: is it an `id` or an object?

Comment: @IgorMoraru I only get the title e.g. ("Calle As de Oro, Praderas del Potrero, 42995 Atotonilco de Tula, Hgo, México") but I can store the id

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yep that makes sense, thanks